# Error bars in pivot graphs Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-chart

I have some data, in which a calculated probability is presented, it's standard deviation, and a couple of "settings" leading to the probability.
When I make a pivor-chart out of this, I can nicely show the data and play with it, but I don't know how to add error bars from the calculated standard deviation (which I have in a column in the data-tab). I would like the size of the error bars to be (for instance) the average of the underlying data in the standard deviation column.

I know how to add error bars for regular graphs in excel, but for pivot-chart this doesn't really work.

Help is much appreciated.

Regards,
Eddy

---

**Update**: Link to my data file: https://we.tl/Lez8jMlG11

To be clear: I want to make a pivot-chart with the average of the column *Average* on the y-axis with the average of the column *Standard_Deviation* as Error Bars; and the p1,p2,p3.... as parameters on the x-axis, when selected in the pivot-chart.
The averaged values of *Average* and *Standard_Deviation*, must be averaged over it's selecting in the pivotting tool. (I'm not sure how to make this clear, I hope you understand my meaning)

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any images of the problem.  The link to your data says files are deleted in 7 days.  That means your question will become unanswerable and unhelpful to others in a week.  The purpose of the site is to build a knowledge base of solutions for future readers with similar problems.  Please add images to make the question clear, self-contained, and permanent.

Comment: @eddy ,, got the File need some time to execute the exercise.

Comment: @fixer1234 I will add images once I can show an answer, right now there is nothing to show. (other than failed attempts)

Answer (score 1):

**To add error bar to Pivot Chart first create the Chart using required Data and do the followings.**

1. Select the data series for that you want to add error bars.
2. Click the Chart Layout tab.
3. In the Analysis, hit Error Bars and then Error Bars options.
4. Then from the navigation pane just hit the Error Bars.
5. For Error amount, hit the Custom, and then click specify value.

   **OR, you try the below written steps also,,**

A. Select the Graph, click the **+ button** on the right side of it.

B. Then hit the arrow next to Error Bars Check Box and then click the More 
   Options.

C. Add Error Bars.

D. Now, from the Format Error Bars pane, pick the Direction & click Both.

E. Then select the End Style, click Cap.

F. Click Fixed value and enter the value.

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: Rajesh, thanks for your input, it is much appreciated.
I really can't find the Error Bars options you mentioned (I use Excel 2013).
In the Chart Layout Tab I don't see any Error Bar subtab.
The second option I tried before, what I dpon't like about this option that the error bars are fixed, instead of representing the data I have in the Standard deviation column. Also, when i specify the error bars via the custom button, I don't get what I want, since specifying which cells to take isn't sufficient. (It doesn't average the cells corresponding to the data in the pivot graphs).

Comment: Please upload the sample data, will help me to improvise my Solution.

Comment: I just added the data.

Comment: By using few of your data I've successfully made the Pivot Chart Graph and also applied the Error Bar. Since I'm using 2013 so I've used the second method what I've suggested you. CLICK the + sign. Other your sheet has to be saved as Workbook  since was CSv file. Also it has tons of rows so if you are thinking to ADD ALL is difficult coz Excel graph allows maximum 255 Data Series.

Comment: By using the + sign, and going to the error bar pane, I can add error bars, but not consisting of the average of the standard deviation in the table. Or do you have a workaround that I am missing?
I can add error bars in a single graph, but the idea of a pivot chart is that you can select and/or de-select parameters. Adjusting this selection will ruin the error bars in my graph. Or am I doing something different from what you are doing?